# What is this icon theme?

Tags: icons, themes

I would like to know what this theme of icons is.
[image: link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say from these handful of icons (also many icons belonging to a specific theme often go through drastic changes over time), but it looks like the Paper icon theme.

[**Paper** Icon theme by **Sam Hewitt**](https://snwh.org/paper)

[image]
([get it from GNOME-LOOK](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1099618/))

Also the following ones look close too.

1. **Flat Remix** ([get it from GNOME-LOOK](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1012430/))
   [image]
2. **Papirus** ([get it from GNOME-LOOK](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1166289/))
   [image]